# batch file parameter input

Tags: batch-file, parameters, cmd

Trying to get fun with batch files. Problem is in this simple code when I'm trying to pass two or more digit number as second param it reads just tens.
Ex.

```
C:\.....>power.bat 2 10
2 power 10 result is 2
C:\.....>power.bat 2 20
2 power 10 result is 4
```

, for one digit number as second param out put is always right.
Code below:

```
@echo off
if "%1" == "" goto :help
if "%2" == "" goto :help
set result=1
set counter=1
:loopstart1
    set /a "result *= %1"
    set /a "counter += 1"
IF "%counter%" LEQ "%2" (GOTO :loopstart1) ELSE (echo %1 pow %2 result is %result%)

goto:eof

:help
echo raise value1 power value2, pass 2 parameters
```

Comment: Remove the quotation marks in your `if` condition: to do a numeric comparison: `IF %counter% LEQ %2`; otherwise, string comparison is done, meaning that it is done character by character...

Comment: works ! Thank you very much :)